# Letting one div shrink if needed

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but I've so far been unable to find anything that works.

I have a sticky nav bar with some breadcrumbs etc and under certain circumstances one of the items might have a very long name.  This forces the items on the far right to drop down on smaller screens.

Here is a mock what happens.
[image]

I want the really long line section to be able to shrink in cases where it would run into the others, always having the username and "logout" on the same line with the rest.  When the long title section is too long, it should truncate and use ellipses.

```
     <div id="topNav" >
            <div class="toolBar">
                <div class="leftTools">
                    <div class="">
                        <span class="icon-group glyphicon"></span>
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="index">Base</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="breadcrumb" class="">                            
                        <a class="listPageLink" href="">
                            <span class="icon-carrot-right glyphicon"></span>
                            <span class="linkText">Type</span>
                        </a>                            
                        <a class="itemPageLink" href="">
                            <span class="icon-carrot-right glyphicon"></span>
                            <span class="linkText">stupid really long title for something wow is this name way too long to be useful for anything</span>
                        </a>                            
                        <a class="subCatPageLink" href="">
                            <span class="icon-carrot-right glyphicon"></span>
                            <span class="linkText">subcat</span>
                        </a>                            
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="rightTools">
                    <div class="">
                        <a>@User.GetName()</a>
                        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="fadeBorder"></div>
        </div>
```

What I don't want:
I don't want to have to use javascript (if at all possible), just CSS.
I don't want to have to write a bunch of media queries for different screen widths.
I would rather not use css calc but if that is the only way then that is ok.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit:  Here is a jsfiddle of the basic idea.
https://jsfiddle.net/1h4maehs/

Edit2:  This codepen is a better exaple:  http://codepen.io/Nurdyguy/pen/dpdwGb

Comment: Post css and a working jsfiddle makes it more easy for help.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `calc()`?

Comment: @hungerstar I'm not completely opposed to it, but if possible I would rather not use it.  This feels like something that should be possible without it and I'm just missing the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox and `text-overflow:ellipsis` can help but it does require you to specify which items you do **not** want to shrink.

Like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
li {
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.no-shrink {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li class="no-shrink">lorem</li>
    <li class="no-shrink">Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, facere.</li>
    <li class="no-shrink">lorem</li>
    <li class="no-shrink">lorem</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li class="no-shrink">lorem</li>
    <li class="no-shrink">Lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li class="no-shrink right">lorem</li>
    <li class="no-shrink">lorem</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can also create a "float:right` option, if required, for the last couple of items.

Comment: I've been trying to use flexbox but (and you can't tell this from above) the user name and "logout" are part of a `float:right` which then no longer works inside the flexbox.

Comment: Moving things to the right is no problem in flexbox. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bwLQBN

Comment: That helped, thanks.  I now have it partially doing what I want.  As I make the window narrower, the long line begins to shrink and turns into ellipses, but only to a point.  After maybe 100px is stops shrinking and then the stuff on the right is off the side of the screen.  Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Here is what I have: http://codepen.io/Nurdyguy/pen/dpdwGb  this works great at first but it stops shrinking when you get to the "f" in "useful".  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I was able to find the issue described in my last comment.  When you use flexbox and `white-space:nowrap` there can be issues.  The solution for that can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-doesnt-flex-item-shrink-past-content-size

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd implement `text-overflow: ellipsis;` while giving each breadcrumb a maximum amount of space each can take up. If they exceed it, add ellipsis and hide the rest.

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 25%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.divider {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <span class="item">Apple</span>
  <span class="divider">></span>
  <span class="item">Banana</span>
  <span class="divider">></span>
  <span class="item">Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry Cranberry</span>
  <span class="divider">></span>
  <span class="item">Doh!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think my underlying issue is that there is a lot of other stuff going on on the page which is complicating the matter.  I have tried what you have here and it isn't quite what I want.  The issue is that sometimes there is plenty of space for the whole title and in that case I want to show it.  In other circumstances it won't fit so I do the ellipses stuff.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll have to ruminate a bit on that. Unknown text lengths are a bit of a moving target.